# Spring JPA filter performance

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate, elasticsearch

I have to implement filtering and searching in Spring and need some advice on the right tools and algorithms. Right now, the decision seems to be, if I use Spring Elasticsearch or do everything on my own. I know that this is a "depends-on" question, but I try to be precise with my requirements and assumptions.

So what I need is

- I basically want to filter my tables by some criteria that clearly returns true or false for each column and I will mostly have one column that has some text value. If my username is UserName123 I would like to find him by userName13 too and get the closest results for my input.

My assumptions about my database

- Tables will have 100k - 300k records
- I don't have to do a lot of joins, but sometimes there will be joins used.
- After applying the clear filters like `is x = y` I will usually have 50-100 records left that I have to apply the name filtering on.
- performance on write access should be considered too

I hope somebody can give me an advice on whether I should index my data and/or use ElasticSearch

Thanks in advance!